# postTweet method return nulls

Tags: java, android, json

This is my code :

```
 PostTweetDialog.java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.codepath.apps.mysimpletweet.models.Tweet;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by AlecksJohanssen on 4/1/2016.
 */
public class PostTweetDialog extends DialogFragment  {

    private RestClient client;
    private PostTweetInterface dialogFragment;
    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;
    TweetArrayAdapter adapter;
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_tweet, null);
        EditText etComposeTweet = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.posttxt);
        final String body = String.valueOf(etComposeTweet.getText());
        tweets = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new TweetArrayAdapter(tweets);
        AlertDialog.Builder TweetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        TweetDialog.setTitle("Post Tweet");
        TweetDialog.setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        client.postTweet(body, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject json) {
                                Tweet myNewTweet = Tweet.fromJSON(json);
                                Log.d("DEBUG",String.valueOf(json.toString()));
                                tweets.add(myNewTweet);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                                Log.d("Error", errorResponse.toString());
                            }

                        });

                    }

                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialogFragment.onDialogNegativeClick(PostTweetDialog.this);
            }
        });
        return TweetDialog.create();

    }
```

This is my PostTweet method:

```
    public void postTweet(String body, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) {
    String apiUrl = getApiUrl("statuses/update.json");
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("status", body);
    getClient().post(apiUrl, params, handler);
}
```

post_tweet.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/posttxt"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="Input your Tweet here" />
</LinearLayout>
```

TimelineActivity.java

```
public class TimelineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PostTweetDialog PostDialog = new PostTweetDialog();
    private RestClient client;
    private ArrayList<Tweet> Tweet;
    private TweetArrayAdapter taAdapter;
    private RecyclerView rvItems;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);
        rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
        Tweet = new ArrayList<>();
        taAdapter = new TweetArrayAdapter(Tweet);
        rvItems.setAdapter(taAdapter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        client = RestApplication.getRestClient();
        populateTimeline(1);
        rvItems.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                populateTimeline(page);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public void doThis(MenuItem item)
    {
        PostDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragment_dialog");
    }

    private void populateTimeline(int page) {
        client.getHomeTimeline(new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                Tweet.addAll(com.codepath.apps.mysimpletweet.models.Tweet.fromJSONArray(response));
                int curSize = taAdapter.getItemCount();
                taAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, Tweet.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
            }
        }, page);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


}
```

}
I don't know why I cannot use my postTweet method, it always return null value.
Here is a gif for the error [NullValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ9rS.gif)

Thanks in advance :D.
P/S : It said null on this line  `client.postTweet(body, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {`

Comment: As far as I can see, you never initialize `client` in your class `PostTweetDialog`. Therfore `client` is `null`.

Comment: So any recommendation for that @SaschaKolberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment you did not initialize client in your dialog class. You could change your activity code to pass the client as argument:

```
public class TimelineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PostTweetDialog PostDialog;
    private RestClient client;
    private ArrayList<Tweet> Tweet;
    private TweetArrayAdapter taAdapter;
    private RecyclerView rvItems;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);
        rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvItems);
        Tweet = new ArrayList<>();
        taAdapter = new TweetArrayAdapter(Tweet);
        rvItems.setAdapter(taAdapter);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        client = RestApplication.getRestClient();
        PostDialog = new PostTweetDialog(client);

        ...
     }
     ...
 }
```

And add an according constructor to the dialog class:

```
public class PostTweetDialog extends DialogFragment  {
    private RestClient client;
    private PostTweetInterface dialogFragment;
    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;
    TweetArrayAdapter adapter;

    public PostTweetDialog(RestClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

To address you question, why `client` is `null`:

Lets have a look at the code of PostTweetDialog...

In one of the first lines of the class you *declare* the private variable `client`:

```
    private RestClient client;
```

then in `onCreate` you set an`onClick` callback that uses that `client`.

```
        TweetDialog.setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        client.postTweet(body, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() { ... });
```

However, nowhere within the class `PostTweetDialog` can I find an assignment to that vartiable. Therefore, within `PostTweetDialog` `client`  is always undefined aka `null`.

As you probably want to use the same `RestClient` that is used by the activity, you have several options.

1. You can pass `client` reference to the dialog class either via constructor (as showcased in my original answer) or via *setter*.
2. You can set the activity as `OnClickListener` and implement `onClick` in the activity, which already has the `client`. But then you need to pass a reference of the activitiy to the dialog class.

Comment: Sir your's method work perfectly. Anyway do you have any mail or something? there is a question I need to ask you if you don't mind :D. Btw Thank you very much ,sir .

Comment: @AlecksJohansson If yoou have a question you can ask it in [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108039/posttweet-method-return-nulls)

Comment: I must have 20 reputations in order to chat to you :'(.

Comment: @AlecksJohansson hm, forgot about that :(, then just ask here.

Comment: Your method is working but I still don't know why its null at client.postTweet(body, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(). Something is wrong with the (body). It could be something with the EditText is null also, p/s java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode null object. Here is the error

Comment: Something wrong with the EditText although I have already put some value that I type in but It still keep saying java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot encode null object

Comment: @AlecksJohansson You need to move the assignment of `body` down inside the `onClick` method. Because  you need to extract the text when `onClick` is called. As it is now you get the text before you enter it and thus `null`.

Comment: Ahh Great. It works probably. Thank you kindly Mr @Sascha Kolberg